# Weird lists in R when returning from xpath

Tags: html, r, list, xpath, vector

I usually use c++ and am new to R. I don't quite know how to deal with this data type that I'm getting when I return something from xpath.

I believe it is a list. I want to convert it to a vector. I know if it were an ordinary list like this:

```
> testlist = list(1,2,3,4,5)
> testlist
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4

[[5]]
[1] 5
```

and I could do `unlist` and get back:

```
> testvec = unlist(testlist)
> testvec
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
>
```

my problem however is that when I use the xpath, I get something like:

```
test 
[[1]]
ABT 

[[2]]
ABBV 

[[3]]
ACE 

[[4]]
ACN 

[[5]]
ACT
```

if I try to do `unlist`, I just get:

```
> unlist(test)
[[1]]
ABT 

[[2]]
ABBV 

[[3]]
ACE 

[[4]]
ACN 

[[5]]
ACT 

[[6]]
ADBE
```

So I guess this is a list, but it's a list of chars with no indexes? I can't write this to a file, or I get:

```
> write(unlist(test), file = "test.txt")
Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

even though I can do:

```
> write(unlist(testlist), file = "testlist.txt")
```

just fine. I can't seem to find any instructions on how to convert this weird list I've got. I don't even know how I could reproduce something.

To show an individual case of what I'm doing, I'll show you what I get from my path.

```
 > library(XML)
 > wikiurl = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
 > urlcontent = htmlTreeParse(wikiurl, useInternal = TRUE)
 > myxpath = "//div[@id='content' and @class='mw-body']/div[@id='bodyContent']/div[@id='mw-content-text']/table/tr[2]/td[1]/a/text()"
 > returnval = xpathSApply(urlcontent, myxpath)
 > returnval
 [[1]]
 ABT
```

once again, I'm getting this weird list of a char with no indices. Shouldn't it look something like:

```
 > reutrnval
 [[1]]
 [1] ABT
```

So either I'm not doing xpath the proper way or I there's something I should know more about lists. I just can't find any examples of this particular case. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your XPath is asking for the anchor text for the first table cell in row 2. That's what you got? What are you trying to retrieve from the table?

Comment: You can also do `sapply(returnval, as, "character")` if you forget to use `xmlValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell what an object is by just how it prints to the console. What you're seeing is the result of calling `print()` on that object. If you want to know what type of object you are seeing, try looking at `class()`

```
class(returnval[[1]])
# [1] "XMLInternalTextNode" "XMLInternalNode"     "XMLAbstractNode"
```

so what you're getting is the XML node representation from the library. This is not a simple data type so you cannot collapse it to a vector with `unlist()` like you can do with atomic types. If you actually want to extract the text from the text node, you typically call `xmlValue` on that node. You can add that to your xpathSApply.

```
returnval = xpathSApply(urlcontent, myxpath, xmlValue)
returnval
# [1] "ABT"
class(returnval)
# [1] "character"
```

Now you are getting as simple character vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to grab the first column, I'd use `rvest`:

```
library(rvest)

wikiurl <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
myxpath <- "//div[@id='content' and @class='mw-body']/div[@id='bodyContent']/div[@id='mw-content-text']/table/tr/td[1]/a/text()"

pg <- html(wikiurl)

pg %>% html_nodes(xpath=myxpath) %>% html_text()
##   [1] "ABT"   "ABBV"  "ACE"   "ACN"   "ACT"   "ADBE"  "ADT"   "AES"   "AET"  
##  [10] "AFL"   "AMG"   "A"     "GAS"   "APD"   "ARG"   "AKAM"  "AA"    "ALXN" 
## ...
## [487] "WFM"   "WMB"   "WIN"   "WEC"   "WYN"   "WYNN"  "XEL"   "XRX"   "XLNX" 
## [496] "XL"    "XYL"   "YHOO"  "YUM"   "ZMH"   "ZION"  "ZTS"
```

Comment: Wow, that was really efficient. Thanks for showing me that.